# Why database does not recognize the columns and table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a table in there is data in the table,
I can insert, update ect.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cse_reports_month](
    [report_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [starburst_dept_name] [varchar](50) NULL,
....more collumns
    [shooting_total_stars] [float] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

but for some reason when I hover over the columns name, for example
select the top 1000 rows :

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [report_id]
      ,[starburst_dept_name]
      ,[starburst_dept_average]
    ...... more columns
      ,[rising_star_dept_name]
  FROM [Intranet].[dbo].[cse_reports_month]
```

It says "invalid column name 'starburst_dept_name'"
It like it does not requinize it, but all my other tables are 
good.
Wondering why it does not recognize the columns?

I have 
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  10.0.2531.0

Comment: Are you sure that the `CREATE TABLE` statement was executed in the correct database context?, in this case the later `SELECT` is pointing to the `Intranet` database

Comment: You are using the 3 part name `[Intranet].dbo.*`, i.e. including the database in the query. Are you sure that there isn't more than one database on the server, with different versions of the table, viz one with, and one without, this column?

Comment: @stuartLC there are more than one database, Intranet is one, but I dont see only one table cse_reports_month

Comment: @user3408399 That doesn't answer if you are sure that you executed the `CREATE TABLE` in that database or not

Comment: @lamak Yes I do remember I did it in the correct database

Comment: @user3408399 But isn't there a way to make **sure** of that?

Comment: @lamak Is there a way to make it was created in the database ? im not sure

Comment: If the table already existed in the `Intranet` database, then the `CREATE TABLE` would've given you an error. You may have created the table in the `master` database, I can't know for sure. But you have access to your servers, look up your table in another database and make sure that you indeed executed your statement in the right databse